# C# Video Playback

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm looking at trying to create a simple 'slider puzzle' game. You've seen the ones, you have an image and you shuffle the tiles.

However, I want to make one that will play back videos instead. What I'm trying to determine is whether it's possible to playback a video in C# and render the video on different controls (probably buttons, or panels). I've spotted the Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback classes but haven't found much documentation on them yet.

So to throw it up in the air, is this going to be possible to do without too much difficulty? Are there any useful (free) libraries that might help me along?

Comment: If you're not set on WinForms, this seems like something WPF would be good at. You can have a brush whose contents are a video (which will magically keep playing wherever you use the brush), and you can do transforms, so I'd guess it wouldn't be too hard to have a control that's filled with a rectangular subset of the currently-playing video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [DirectShowNet](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/) that wraps the DirectShow API, in the [samples](http://directshownet.sourceforge.net/about.html) page there is a sample called PlayWnd the shows how to play a video file.

Answer (score 0):

Depending upon how large and how long your video sources are, you could accomplish this very simply by first converting your videos to animated GIFs.  A .Net PictureBox control will display and animate a GIF automatically, and you could easily use PictureBoxes for your tiles.

One big advantage of this approach is that (thanks to Mono) your application could work unaltered on Windows, Mac and the iPhone (also Linux and a couple others).

Comment: It's an interesting idea, but not sure its feasible. Depends on the amount of pre-processing required.

Comment: @Ian: actually, if you're intending to show just one video broken up into separate movable tiles, the GIF idea wouldn't work at all, because the separate pieces wouldn't be kept syncronized in their PicturesBoxes (at least I think they wouldn't).